# What file types can be visualized in ParaView using NVIDIA IndeX plugin?

Tags: data-visualization, paraview, openfoam

I have made some work using OpenFOAM and now want to visualize my data using ParaView, when I loaded `.foam` file and some `.stl` files, I cannot see the NVIDIA IndeX option from the dropdown, thus I assume that not all the data type can be rendered by IndeX.

Refer to this [page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/index-paraview-plugin.html), only structured and unstructured volume data can be rendered by IndeX, what does it mean?

is there any way to make my data IndeX readied?

Comment: Please describe how you tried to set up the IndeX plugin. From where did you download ParaView? Did you load the plugin in the Plugin Manager?

Comment: @CoryQuammen I download `ParaView` from [here](https://www.paraview.org/download/) and `IndeX` plugin from [here](https://forum.nvidia-arc.com/showthread.php?16479-NVIDIA-IndeX-for-ParaView-plugin-1-2-released!). Installation processes are pretty much straightforward and yes, `pvNVIDIAIndeX` plugin is loaded through `Tools > Manage Plugins`... menu in ParaView

Comment: If you go to the Sources menu and choose Wavelet, does the IndeX representation appear in the drop down?

Comment: @CoryQuammen you mean this one right? https://imgur.com/a/Kt84T yes IndeX representation appear on Wavelet source test.

Comment: anyway, do you have any working case file for me to download and test IndeX plugin? I have tried with some of the publicly available .vtk files on the Internet and all of them behave same: the rendered model disappear from the window upon changing to IndeX. This issue already asked on [NVIDIA forum here](https://forum.nvidia-arc.com/showthread.php?16517-Is-my-dataset-incompatible-with-Nvidia-Index-plug-in) but seems no reply from NVIDIA.

Comment: Wavelet is a structured grid. It appears your plugin is working. Your data set needs to have volumetric cells, either hexahedra arranged in a type of regular lattice (structured) or tetrahedra (unstructured) grid. I don't know if IndeX can render other types of cells besides tetrahedra in an unstructured grid.

Can you share the OpenFOAM data set you are trying to render with IndeX?